# How to avoid unexpected user operations interrupt RPA workflow with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui, rpa

I am using `pyautogui` to implement a RPA workflow to collect data from a controller software. A problem is the automation workflow have several steps and it may take about 10s to finish，and unexpected user operations may interrupt the workflow. Is there any way to avoid this? For example, to "freeze" specific windows, or even freeze the whole desktop until the workflow finish.